# Express route with multible slash - Linux & Windows difference

Tags: node.js, express

I have encountered a strange behaviour with express routes. I want to enter an ID via HTML-Form and fetch the result via ajav (jquery) to display the entry. All was working fine, till i have to expand the ID from numbers to strings (with slashes).

I edited all functions and calls. I check the strign with a reg ex and want to fetch the request with a modified route (express). but here comes the problem. i get it working under windows but it is failing on linux. Perhaps the problem is caused by the invrastructure, because the node.js app is located behind an reverse proxy apache2 to tunnel the service to public (with domain & cert).

what ever. perhaps somebody can help me set this thing up and get it running.

```
app.get(/^\/byId\/(.+)/, getSourceById);
```

not using req.params[0] in the called function. on the test server (windows) it is working even with the old route

```
app.get('/byId/:id', getSourceById);
```

because the html form does request %2F not /. How ever, both ways should work to fetch the request. But both aren't working for me. did i miss something?

i'm thankful for any help!

Comment: Can you provide examples of the route(s) that are causing errors with `:id`?  I think I get the question, but seeing the actual route strings would confirm.  :)

Comment: Sure. Sorry, that I did not provide a example in first place. Alle routes are working as long as no slash is in the URL. Failing routes on Linux: ...com/byId/TEST-12/23 as well as  ...com/byId/TEST-12%2F23 ... Apache (Reverse Proxy) delivering 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer of my question. It was indeed the reverse proxy who was blocking the request.

> Simular problem: http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/apache/users/314562

How to solve the behaviour:

> http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes

Default forbidden because of security issues. If you need it, use it carefully.